# Why rabbitmq's queue binding is auto changed?

Tags: java, clojure, rabbitmq

I create a queue "a.1" , a exchange "a"  and bind them together through a rabbitmq channel. This channel is in a connnection which has about 3 hundreds channels.After running normally for 20-30 minutes,the binding is disappeared and the queue is binded to default exchange. I watched it in rabbitmq admin,I saw the queue was once closed and auto-recovered.After the recovering,I could see the channel was changed.channel info:ip:2341 (633),the port is changed to ip:3350.But the queue is binded to default exchange.Why rabbitmq has this strange behavior?How to avoid it?

Comment: What does the following mean "his channel is in a connnection which has about 3 hundreds channels" ?How do you create the exchange, i.e. what do you set as autodelete flag? How do you bind queues? Some code would be nice...

Comment: 1,get a rabbitmq connection 2, get a channel from the connection.3 create a exchange ,4 create a queue with params::exclusive   false :auto-delete true. Repeat 2,3,4 for 300 times,so this channels using one connection.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it ... Why would you create a connection every time if you have just one client? Also you didn't say how do you create an exchange.

Comment: some threads in the client subscribe different queues.They shared one connecition. Each thread uses a channel.THe exchange is created with durable     true :auto-delete false fanout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `auto-delete` queues, which means that if all consumers go down queue will be deleted automatically. Then another channel can recreate queue with same name.
So if you are creating queues with same names you can make sure it's bound avery time when created. Or you can add expiration TTL for auto-deleting queues to wait for some time before deletion (to allow another channel to start consuming).